# All of my launchers keep crashing, my only fix is to factory reset. I need help for backing up valuable data

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, backup

I have a Galaxy S2 running on ICS. It is not rooted.

Recently it keeps crashing. No app will start with the exception of lock screen and the notification curtain. My menu button does not work so during my research on this problem the "download GO Launcher and set as default > clear data" solution will not work. I want to keep this post as short as possible so here are some links on my *first* problem:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1417244

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1541223

(These two posters fixed their problems due to their menu buttons being able to function).

Looks like my only fix is to do a factory reset (though if anyone has a few suggestions, please post them!).

Unfortunately not being able to access any apps means **I cannot do back ups**. I want to restore my phone to the pre-crash state as much as possible. I have a valuable memo on the "Memo" app that comes with TouchWiz. Can this be done?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that it's best not to void my warranty by flashing or rooting. My S2 has some screen burn ins that I need to get fixed and they'll be checking.

Comment: If y'all came to Sprint you wouldn't have to worry about ROMs and rooting. They give support and repair regardless of root now. Jussayin ;)

Comment: Good to know, however: I only buy my phones unbranded for some time. SEMC (and others?) don't allow to unlock a bootloader if it's a branded phone (for fear of sim unlocking I guess)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic walkthrough for any phone:

---

**Alternative 1:**

1. Flash a CWM [recovery](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager)
   For Samsung, use [Heimdall](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/downloads). download for 'Galaxy S2' or 'SGH-i777', depending on what you own
   Heimdall also supports a *dump* command that can be used to backup all flash beforehand
   Command to flash: `heimdall flash --recovery CWM-recovery.img`
2. [Enter](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=How%20to:%20Samsung%20Galaxy%20S2%20recovery%20mode) the newly installed CWM recovery
3. Do a backup in CWM to your external sdcard (be sure there's enough space left)
4. switch off & check the backup on your PC (it's located in `/clockworkmod/backup/ on the sdcard`)
5. If you're sure your backup is OK, enter CWM again and do a full wipe
6. Reboot your phone, do the first-time-init (Google Account and such)
7. Install [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) + its [Pro key](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro)
8. in Titanium Backup: **extract from nandroid backup**

---

**Alternative 2:**

- Applicable if your fastboot mode supports the extended command 'boot'
- Compatible devices: Google's Nexus Line, HTC Desire with patched HBOOT loader and others

Steps:

1. Enter fastboot mode and load a recovery into RAM (without flashing): `fastboot boot recovery.img`
2. Continue with step 3 from 'Alternative 1'

---

**Alternative 3** (Samsung only, but broken on Galaxy S i9000):

*not tried yet, see this as an idea as for now. You're on your own with errors on extraction & restore*

[Heimdall](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/downloads) implements a 'dump' and command and a means to print the partition table (PIT):

`heimdall dump --chip-type NAND --chip-id 0 --output nanddump.out.img`
`heimdall print-pit` **or** `heimdall download-pit --output nand.out.pit`

You may then cut the NAND dump into pieces (one for each partition) and name them accordingly. If successfull, you can then access your data and continue at *Alternative 1, step 8 or 4*

Comment: Thanks will try this when I get home. I didn't specify that I cannot flash but this seems like a last resort anyways (post updated with more info on that). There is absolutely no way I can back up app data without flashing/rooting? Not even through Kies?

Comment: If you want to wait, I have a chance to test with a  S2 tomorrow. But at least, the heimdall dump will work without any changes: 'heimdall[.exe] dump --chip-type NAND --chip-id 0 --output out.img' The stored data in the complete dump is however not easy to extract and generate a backup from it.

Comment: I can wait, no problem. Thanks a million for putting in the effort for me.

Comment: I added 2 more ways for getting your data back (2nd was in a comment I deleted)

Comment: @meiryo: had no chance to test on friday (it's a pool device). Do you still need those findings? (tomorrow is the next chance)

Comment: Very sorry for the late response (I lost my password for this account) but resorted to method 1 and it worked well. Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: Nice! Thanks for letting me know. You can buy Triangle Away to reset the flash counter and revert to an orig. Recovery if you want to send it in for replacement under warranty

Answer (score 0):

As you are running ICS, you might want to take a look at the question [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices). All you need for that is the Android SDK on your computer. Starting with ICS, full backups are supported this way even if you are not rooted. Details can be found in the linked question's answers.